# Maven warning 'Overriding managed version 2.5.3 for maven-release-plugin'

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

When I try to use maven-release-plugin in pom.xml, I am getting the following Warning:

```
Overriding managed version 2.5.3 for maven-release-plugin
```

I do not have parent pom. My pom.xml is to create standalone jar file. why is the above warning generated? where does maven get the version 2.5.3 ?

Here is my plugin info in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <goals>pre-integration-test</goals>
        <preparationGoals>package</preparationGoals>
        <allowTimestampedSnapshots>true</allowTimestampedSnapshots>
        <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
        <remoteTagging>false</remoteTagging>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the full pom file otherwise it's hard to check ...

Answer (score 0):

> ### [Super POM](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html)
>
> All models implicitly inherit from a super-POM:
>
> ```xml
>    ...
>    <pluginManagement>
>      ...
>        <plugin>
>          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
>          <version>2.5.3</version>
>        </plugin>
> ```